# Print out warning if found nothing using glob - TCL

Tags: tcl, warnings, message

My script is as below. I would like to print out a warning if I cant glob any thing from the directory.

How do I print a warning in the foreach loop when it cant find any file that match the $food and $toy combination?

```
foreach value $list {

set file1 [ open "$food/$toys/abc.txt"]

set list1 [glob -nocomplain -type f /a/$food/$toys/*]
puts $file1 [join $list1 \n]

close $file1

}
```

Comment: Hint: $list1 is empty if `[glob -nocomplain]` can't find any matched file

Comment: Another hint: Without `-nocomplain` `[glob]` throws an error if it can't find a match, and there's `[catch]` or `[try]` to deal wit errors

Comment: So, you are saying dont use -nocomplain? Can you give example how to use the catch?

Comment: I'm saying that there are several ways of doing what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You'd also want to catch errors from `open` (Speaking of which, you need to open the file for writing which you're not doing), not just `glob`.

Something like:

```
# You don't use value in your posted code. Typo or something?
foreach value $list {
    try {
        set list1 [glob -type f "/a/$food/$toys/*"]
        set file1 [open "$food/$toys/abc.txt" w]
        puts $file1 [join $list1 \n]
        close $file1
    } on error {msg} {
        puts stderr "Error while processing '$value': $msg"
    }
}
```

will handle both cases, and any other errors that might be raised.

Comment: When I execute the above, it is saying invalid command name "try". Do I have to use a special tcl version. I am using tclsh8.5.